# How to call a python function with annotations?

Tags: python, html, django, annotations

I have a function in another annotated method and there is a problem. I call it through django and get all sorts of errors.[image] like this.

**views.py:**
`

```
def callbot():
    bot_activate = bot.Command.callBot()
    
    return render(request, bot_activate)

def output(request, temlate_name='custom_change_form.html',):
    callbot()
    print('work')


    return render(request, temlate_name)
```

`**bot.py**`

```
@logerrors
def do_echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext,):
    print('HELLOOOOO')
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    text = update.message.text
    p, _ = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
        external_id=chat_id,
        defaults={
            'name': update.message.from_user.username,
        }
    )
    MessagePanel(
        profile=p,
        text=text,
    ).save()
    reply_text = f"Your ID: {chat_id} \n{text} \n "
    update.message.reply_text(text=reply_text,) 


@logerrors
def send_text(update: Update, context: CallbackContext,):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    text = update.message.text
    commandname = CommandsForButtons.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    print('Its worked')
    for mess in commandname:
        mess_send = mess.command_text
        update.message.reply_text(text=f'It\'s test message: {mess_send}')
    do_echo(update, context)

@logerrors
def send_hand_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext,):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    text = update.message.text
    hand_message = HandMadeMessage.objects.all()
    update.message.reply_text(text=f'It\'s test message: {hand_message}')



class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Telegram-Bot'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        hand_message = HandMadeMessage.objects.all()
        
        request = Request(
            connect_timeout=0.5,
            read_timeout=1.0,
        )
        bot = Bot(
            request=request,
            token=settings.TOKEN,
            base_url=getattr(settings, 'PROXY_URL', None),
        )

        to_bot_panel, _  = BotsPanel.objects.get_or_create(
            bot_id = bot.get_me().id,
            bot_name = bot.get_me().first_name,
            bot_nickname= bot.get_me().username,
            bot_token= bot.token
        )

        print(bot.get_me())

        updater = Updater(
            bot=bot,
            use_context=True,
        )
        #Commands
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('get', send_text,))
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, do_echo))
            
        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()

        
    def callBot():
        return send_text(Update, CallbackContext)
```

`
Maybe u guys know what i should to do))))
I don’t know how to solve this problem, and I don’t ask you to write code, if anyone has the opportunity to explain, then I beg you, do it haha))

Comment: okey, i can't find a way to solve this problem, but now i know that MessageHandler gives parameters into func.

Answer (score 0):

`chat_id = update.message.chat_id`
Shouldn't this be
`chat_id = update.message.chat.id` ?

In your example, in the first function you use `chat.id`, then in the following methods you use `chat_id`.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. No its could be chat_id. I just forgot to correct the error there